# Lower bound for the radius convergence of series solutions about x = 0 for $(x^2-2x+2)y’’ + ln(1+x)y’ - xy = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

***My attempt:***

$P(x)= x^2-2x+2$, $Q(x)= \ln(1+x)$, $R(x)= -x$.

Clearly, $P(0) \ne 0$ and $p = \dfrac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$, $q = \dfrac{R(x)}{P(x)}$ are analytic at $x=0$. Therefore, $x=0$ is ordinary point.

Since both the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\dfrac{1}{x^2-2x+2}$ converge when $|x|<1$, $p$ also converges when $|x|<1$.

Moreover, the Taylor series of $q$ converges everywhere.

Thus, the radius of convergence is $\rho = 1$

I would like to know whether my approach is correct and if not, how can I solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to revise the influence of complex roots on the radius of convergence. Thus amending your statement on $q$. The main result is correct.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann: So if I consider the complex root, the radius of convergence of $q$ is $\sqrt{2}$ right?

Comment: Yes, due to the poles at $1\pm i$. But the singularity of the logarithm is closer, so it determines the minimal radius, as you wrote.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann: thank you for the valuable feedback!